# How to setup domain on my home webserver?

Tags: internet, apache2

I have installed webserver apache and I am running the site perfectly with IP.Now I want to get a free domain like .th,.co.vu or similar but I don't. Know how to setup it.My site is new so some free domain will do the,job like above stated domain.So plz guide me step by step as I am little new to Linux and web server.And If you have some good free domain company feel free to share it with me.

Comment: This is not really relevant to Ubuntu.

Comment: I know but I am using Ubuntu for server...and I have setup webserver on it.So I thought it was better to get help here

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy/obtain your domain name, and then read the documentation provided by this registrar to point it at your IP.